# How to debug DNS for domain with no IP?

Tags: dns, github-pages, amazon-route53

I have the domain icebuddha.com that I am trying to associate with a static Github Page (https://github.com/0xdabbad00/icebuddha).  When I ping or dig this address I get no IP see [here](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/icebuddha.com).  I've configured this domain in Route53 as follows:
[image]

Name servers match NS record.  I don't know what the SOA record is.
[image]

Other name server view:
[image]

dig records (normal, notice it has no A records):

```
$ dig icebuddha.com
; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> icebuddha.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 50957
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;icebuddha.com.                 IN      A

;; Query time: 273 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.106.2#53(192.168.106.2)
;; WHEN: Sat Jun 18 13:11:26 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 31
```

dig records when I specify the name server to use (notice it does have A records, which is good):

```
$ dig icebuddha.com @ns-10.awsdns-01.com

; <<>> DiG 9.8.4-rpz2+rl005.12-P1 <<>> icebuddha.com @ns-10.awsdns-01.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 18793
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;icebuddha.com.                 IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
icebuddha.com.          300     IN      A       192.30.252.154
icebuddha.com.          300     IN      A       192.30.252.153

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
icebuddha.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-10.awsdns-01.com.
icebuddha.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-1447.awsdns-52.org.
icebuddha.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-1607.awsdns-08.co.uk.
icebuddha.com.          172800  IN      NS      ns-737.awsdns-28.net.

;; Query time: 69 msec
;; SERVER: 205.251.192.10#53(205.251.192.10)
;; WHEN: Sat Jun 18 13:11:43 2016
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 199
```

Comment: Look at your hosted zone in Route 53.  Not the NS records, but the `Name Servers` listed over on the right side of the console, when you first click the domain.  Do these match your NS records shown here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution was to ensure all three mentions of Name Servers and NS records are the same. By using that last image as the authoritive answer, and setting the middle image to those values, this worked.